# Python module imports polluted by calling module

Tags: python, mocking, python-import, python-module

I've created module `B`, which does some expensive network calls in its function `foo()`. So I've created a module `mockB` for testing. `mockB` has a method called `mockfoo()`, which is a mock of `B.foo()`, and another called `patch()`, which takes an instance of module `B` as a parameter and overrides its `foo()` method with `mockfoo()`.

**B.py**

```
def foo():
    print 'foo()'
```

**mockB.py**

```
def patch(B_module):
    B_module.foo = mock_foo

def mock_foo():
    print 'mock_foo()'
```

Module `A` imports `B` and `mockB` and uses `mockB` to patch `B`, then calls `B.foo()`. Everything works as expected -- `'mock_foo()'` is printed.

The weirdness comes up when module `A` imports module `C`, which is also a client of `B`, and neither `A` nor `C` patch `C.B`. For some reason, `C.do_B_thing()` prints `'mock_foo()'`.

**C.py**

```
import B

def do_B_thing():
    B.foo()
```

**A.py**

```
import B
import mockB
import C
from B import foo

mockB.patch(B)

# Unsurprising
print 'Calling patched B.foo():'
B.foo()

# Surprising
print 'Module C calling unpatched B.foo():'
C.do_B_thing()

# For comparison
print 'Module C calling local foo():'
foo()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python A.py 
Calling patched B.foo():
mock_foo()
Module C calling unpatched B.foo():
mock_foo()
Module C calling local foo():
foo()
```

Happens in both Python 2.7 and 3 (with print statements changed to function calls as appropriate).

Comment: The python `mock` library's own `mock.patch` requires you to patch each instance of the module you want patched. This seems like incongruous behavior.

Comment: That's because when you import using `from B import foo`, you create a *local reference*, which references the `B.foo()` function *as well*. Mock can only patch that reference, because mocking `B.foo()` will not update other references to the original.

Comment: In other words, when using `from B import foo` in module `A`, you created `A.foo`, a reference to a function object (that happens to have two references now, `B.foo` and `A.foo`).

Comment: In this context, you may want to read [*Where to patch*](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), part of the `unittest.mock` documentation.

Comment: Cool, I added a relevant couple of lines to the question to illustrate that difference. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely expected behaviour.

Modules are *singletons*. There is only one copy in memory (stored in `sys.modules`). Importing loads the module once, then reuses it everywhere it is imported.

As such, there is only *one* `B.foo` object, and you replaced it with another function. Everywhere else uses `B.foo` to look up the reference to the function still, so they see the replaced object.

If you need to mock something temporarily, you need to make sure to re-instate the original object once you are done. The [`mock` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) ([`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html) in Python 3) can do this for you.

Alternatively, create a local reference to the function object. If you use:

```
from B import foo

foo()
```

you created a new reference to `foo` itself. Replacing `B.foo` later on won't alter this 'local' `foo` reference.